# Unable to connect to SQLite in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite

I have pre-defined sqlite database using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). I have place the db file in the path `root/android/app/src/main/assets/www/mysqlite.db`, unfortunately I'm unable to
connect. Below are my versioning.

```
Samsung Galaxy Android 11,
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.4",
```

My script(I make it simplified):

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
SQLite.DEBUG(true);
SQLite.enablePromise(false);

export const AppSignIn = (props) => {
    const OpenDB = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            global.db = SQLite.openDatabase(
                {
                    name: 'mysqlite.db',
                    createFromLocation: '~mysqlite.db',
                },
                () => {
                    console.log("Connection success!");
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject();
                });
            resolve();
        });
    }
    const ReadDB = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            global.db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    // The rest of the trx
                );
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
    async function ConnectDB() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await OpenDB()
                .then(async () => {
                    await ReadDB()
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log('YEAY FINALLY');
                            resolve();
                        })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject();
                });
        });
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await ConnectDB()
                .then()
                .catch();
        })();
    }, []);
}
```

The log writes:

```
LOG  OPEN database: mysqlite.db
LOG  SQLite.open({"name":"mysqlite.db","createFromLocation":"~mysqlite.db","dblocation":"nosync","assetFilename":"~mysqlite.db"})
LOG  new transaction is waiting for open operation
LOG  Phone connected? true, Server connected? true
LOG  OPEN database: mysqlite.db failed, aborting any pending transactions
LOG  [Error: Could not open database]
```

I have tried several ways but I'm unable to connect to it.

1. Move from www to assets folder directly. Uninstall app on phone and run again.
2. Remove `SQLite.enablePromise(false);`
3. react-native link react-native-sqlite-storage
4. cd android && ./gradlew clean
5. Follow step to [opendatabase call](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/master/README.md#step-6---adjust-opendatabase-call)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your file for android from `root/android/app/src/main/assets/www/mysqlite.db` -> `root/android/app/src/main/assets/mysqlite.db`

Comment: Already done based from my post on what i have tried on #1

Answer (score 1):

I finally able to run it on Samsung Galaxy with Android 11. I've tried on Redmi6 with Android 9 and it can run.

I've removing react-native.config.js which contain SQLite

```
module.exports = {
    dependencies: {
        "react-native-sqlite-storage": {
            platforms: {
                android: {
                    sourceDir: "../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android-native",
                    packageImportPath: "import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;",
                    packageInstance: "new SQLitePluginPackage()"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I also remove the import module `import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;` in `MainApplication.java` and the database finally open.

I'm not sure if this way are absolute. I hope it was temporary as it oppose the way from the tutorial.